# Incorrect LRC value calculated from checksum

Tags: python, checksum

I'm trying to calculate an LRC (Longitudinal Redundancy Check) value with Python.
My Python code is pulled from other posts on StackOverflow. It looks like this:

```
lrc = 0
for b in message:
    lrc ^= b
print lrc
```

If I plug in the value '\x02\x47\x30\x30\x03', I get an LRC value of 70 or 0x46 (F)
However, I am expecting a value of 68 - 0x44 (D) instead.

I have calculated the correct LRC value via C# code:

```
byte LRC = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < bytes.Length; i++)
 {
     LRC ^= bytes[i];
 }
 return LRC;
```

If I plug in the same byte array values, I get the expected result of 0x44.

Functionally, the code looks very similar. So I'm wondering what the difference is between the code. Is it my input value? Should I format my string differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are 0-ordered in C#, so by starting iteration from `int i = 1;` you are skipping 1st byte.

Python result is correct one.

Fixed reference code:

```
byte LRC = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
     LRC ^= bytes[i];
}
return LRC;
```

To avoid such mistake you should consider using `foreach` syntactic sugar (although I'm not familiar with C# practices).

/edit

To skip first byte in Python simply use [slice syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation):

```
lrc = 0
for b in message[1:]:
    lrc ^= b
print lrc
```

Comment: Appreciate the input but the C# result is the one I am looking for. The Python implementation is the one that I am unhappy with. Good point with noting that it starts at 1 though. I will explore that further

Answer (score -1):

So I figured out the answer to my question. Thanks to Nsh for his insight. I found a way to make the algorithm work. I just had to skip the first byte in the for-loop. There's probably a better way to do this but it was quick and it's readable.

```
def calcLRC(input):
    input=input.decode('hex')
    lrc = 0
    i = 0
    message = bytearray(input)
    for b in message:
        if(i == 0):
            pass
        else:
            lrc ^= b
        i+=1;
    return lrc
```

It now returns the expected 0x44 in my use case.